# How to get every change notification from couchbase server?

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

Database.addChangeListener not work some time in Couchbase Lite 1.4.4 .

Below is my code

```
 database?.addChangeListener { event ->
    //using for only changed documents
    Log.e("changes",""+event.changes)

   val query = database?.createAllDocumentsQuery()
    query?.allDocsMode = Query.AllDocsMode.ALL_DOCS
    var result: QueryEnumerator? = null
    result = query?.run()
    val it = result

    if (it != null) {
        arrayList.clear()

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            val row = it.next()
            if (row.documentId.startsWith("refill-device-SERIAL-")) {
                obj = JSONObject(row.document.properties)
                val canisters = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), Canisters::class.java)
                arrayList.add(canisters)
            }
        }
    }

    canistersArrayList.postValue(arrayList)
}
```

Above code not fire sometime… What I should do if I want to get every change events from database?

Comment: 1.4.4 is so old that this question is going to be very hard to answer conclusively.  I would suspect, however, that that change listener is *so* slow that it is blocking the thread used to process changes.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.4.4 is several years old; you should really be using a newer version like 2.7, especially if you're just prototyping.

I don’t know why your code wouldn’t be catching all database changes. What particular changes doesn't it handle?

(Also, not directly related, but this code is *extremely* inefficient. You should be looking at the list of changed documents and only updating your data model for the docs that changed, instead of scanning through the entire database every time.)

Comment: because 2.7 version is not compatible with couchdb documents